# Importing HTML into another HTML import

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, import

I've got a small website I'm working on, and have chosen to seperate the navbar (I use Bootstrap) into an external file, so I don't have to re-write it for every file that uses it, every time I make a change to it. This works really well, as I have imported it with the following code:

```
<!-- Loads external files -->
<script>
$(function(){
$("#navbarContent").load("/navbar.html");
});
</script>
```

In my `<body>`, I have the following code where I need the navbar:

```
<div id="navbarContent"></div>
```

The issue is, is that on my index, I have a link in the navbar that smoothly moves to the anchor position on the index page when clicked. What I want, is to be able to instantly move to the anchor when loading from another page other than the index (that works), except smoothly anchor from index itself.

My proposed solution is to simply add in a second import, which will be different based upon each page. In other words, the link to the anchor will have different `href` contents, so I'll store them in seperate files, but it won't work for some reason:

i.e.:

On `index.html`, use the following code:

```
<script>
$(function(){
$("#navbarContent").load("/navbar.html").load("/indexcontact.html");
});
</script>
```

Except what happens is, the entire thing is replaced by `indexcontact.html` instead of adding to `navbar.html`. I've tested with stupid things and this seems to happen no matter what I have in those two files.

**So, is there a way to merge two jQuery loads so I can import both of the imports simply merged together into one huge string?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `$.when` with two AJAX calls and concatenate the output before setting it into the `#navbarContent`.

```
var d1 = $.ajax('/navbar.html');
var d2 = $.ajax('/indexcontact.html');

$.when( d1, d2 ).done(function ( v1, v2 ) {
    $("#navbarContent").html([v1[0], v2[0]].join());
});
```

To know more about `$.when`, you can refer to the jQuery documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/).

Comment: Oh my gosh! That is beautiful! Thankyou! The only issue is, is that it has put `,success,[object Object],` halfway between it.... :/

Comment: @finnrayment My bad! I almost forgot that `v1` and `v2` are arrays with with `data, statusText, jqXHR` properties. jQuery docs to the rescue :)

Comment: Thankyou! Works perfectly. Sorry I couldn't fix it myself, I've got no idea how jQuery works and didn't realise it was an array, only used it because I needed to. :)